# Simple time tracker for Windows?

Tags: windows, time-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Time Tracking Applications](https://superuser.com/questions/917/time-tracking-applications)

I'd like a small Windows application (not web-based) that sits in the icon bar and keep track of time I spend on different projects by providing a simple interface.

Unless there's a real need for them, I don't need more features than a list of project, a Start/Stop button, and some reporting so I can see how much time I spent on the different projects.

[Google returns](http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&q=windows%20time%20tracking%20application%20&meta=) a lot of those, so I'd like some recommendation.

Thank you.

Comment: Our recommendations aren't really different from what you find on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using [Grindstone](http://www.epiforge.com/Grindstone/) for the last six months and it does everything I need it to.

I have added Custom Values for Clients on tasks so I can easily report a task breakdown for both my employers by quickly selecting the tasks on projects which belong to them and produce timesheets, invoice values etc.

You can use it with application tracking if it helps,  but that's no good for me as I work with the same programs for most tasks. I just double click on the right task when I switch Projects.

Comment: I'll check it out, along with OK NCH's TimeSheet

Comment: Grindstone is very very nice

Answer (score 0):

[Rescue Time](http://www.rescuetime.com/) is an interesting application that can give you quite a lot of fine grain information about how you work etc.

It's so good even I paid for it.

Comment: Thanks but RescueTime seems web-based